# Nginx issues after DNS change

Tags: dns, nginx, ip

Basically, I am trying to point my domain to a different IP.

In checking [website/domain](http://www.innowhite.com) , it appears the DNS has propagated over to the new IP address. When visiting the site, I see a 'Welcome to nginx!' message. If I load the IP - `209.105.244.90` directly, it shows the website. I have waited for over 24hrs for the change to take place - but no luck.

What am i missing? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Following is the nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 209.105.244.90;
  root /home/firemonk/myapps/web/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
  passenger_enabled on;
```

}

Comment: What is your current ngingx configuration?  Posting it to the question could help.  Note any includes; you may have some competing `server{}` declarations.

Comment: @LarsRohrbach : Just updated the question with the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

your first server block has

```
server_name localhost;
```

your second server block has

```
server_name 209.105.244.90;
```

in other words, none of your server blocks is set to listen to your domainname
-> add your domainname to the relevant serverblock